# Why isn't this working...?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to show a button to users with appropriate permissions. The best way to do this, I think, is in my template file. So, I have the following:

```
{% if user.hasPermission('create qualification content') %}
SHOW THE BUTTON HERE
{% endif %}
```

I know the user that this permission, I have checked the list of permissions available on site by `$all = array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions());`

But, the button will not show.

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: cache... use preprocess function to add the renderable content and add #cache context for user role or permission.

Comment: @IvanJaros Could you provide a bit more information on how to achieve what you are suggesting? I've really just finding may way into D8 development and I'm not sure what you mean. Many thanks!